# Can PyInstaller exe file be distributed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I converted a .py file to .exe using pyinstaller and made a copy of the whole directory on another machine (same version of OS). What happen is that when I run it, it will prompt some errors.

`developer1` is the machine that developed the script, `user1` is the machine where I distribute the program to.

```
C:\Users\user1\Downloads\MyApp\dist\app>app.exe
c:\users\developer1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "c:\users\developer1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "c:\users\developer1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pxd", line 7, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\c_timestamp.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.c_timestamp
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\users\developer1\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "pandas\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
[10460] Failed to execute script app
```

I checked the `.spec` file and found out that the `pathex` path is actually the developer machine path, I believe this is actually causing all these errors? Is there a fix for this or the .exe is meant to be run on the developer machine only?

Just a side info:

1. I did not use virtual environment when building the application, not sure if this is causing these errors.
2. The `user1` machine do not have python installed

In this `.spec` file

```
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\developer1\\App1'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Do I need bother about the `pathex` being the path of developer machine?

**Update:**

1. Yes pyinstaller exe file can be distributed
2. Most `ModuleNotFoundError` can be solved by using `--hiddenimport` as mentioned in the answer accepted.
3. There's no need to bother about the pathex being different from user path

Comment: looks like a "hiddenimports" might be missing in the .spec file. are you using "one directory" mode or "single file" mode? what is the line you are typing to build the pyinstaller app?

user1 does not need to have python installed and pathx is correct being developer machine specific. Pyinstaller build apps are indeed meant to be easily distributed.

Comment: in addition you should check, if you imported pandas in the app.py module. Pyinstaller infers which packages it includes in the bundle by the imports.
Also you should definetly use virtual envs

Comment: just basic ```pyinstaller app.py```, by default its one directory mode

Comment: add --hiddenimport=pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets

Comment: @b0lleb Don't quite understand you, are you trying to ask if I did import pandas in my py script? If that's the question, yes I do import all the modules in the script, and the script is working perfectly

Comment: yes this was the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type `pyinstaller app.py --hiddenimport=pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets`
when building the app

since you posted the spec file... you can put this in and just use `pyinstaller app.spec`

```
a = Analysis(['app.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\developer1\\App1'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain why is pandas module having this error only but not the other modules like matplotlib?

Comment: like b0lle said, pyinstaller does its best to find what "imports" your code is using. Since pandas is using an additional LIB in its code (a C library, not python), pyinstaller has a hard time finding it automatically. The people that manage pyinstaller have done a really good job at hard coding the finding of a lot of libraries behind the scenes (PyQt, MatPlotlib, tkinter, alot of pandas) but some libs sneak past unnoticed